# Ruby Search Array of Hashes and Arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of hashes which also include an array:

```
machines = [{ 'name' => 'ldapserver1', 'ip' => '10.199.0.10',
         'role' => ['server', 'initial'] },
       { 'name' => 'ldapserver2', 'ip' => '10.199.0.11',
         'role' => ['server', 'secondary'] },
       { 'name' => 'ldapclient1', 'ip' => '10.199.0.12',
         'role' => 'client' },
       { 'name' => 'ldapclient2', 'ip' => '10.199.0.13',
         'role' => 'client' }]
```

I want to search thru it to get the machine with a matching role.

I can use this to get machines with the client role:

```
results = @machines.select { |machine| machine['role'] == 'client' }

[{"name"=>"ldapclient1", "ip"=>"10.199.0.12", "role"=>"client"}, {"name"=>"ldapclient2", "ip"=>"10.199.0.13", "role"=>"client"}]
```

But when I try to search the array of roles this breaks:

```
results = machines.select { |machine| machine['role'] == 'server' }

[]
```

How can I search through the role arrays to find matches for my machines?

Comment: Why do you have an array of hashes? Do you have the flexibility of making it an array of `Machine` objects, for example? If you will be slicing and dicing in various ways it may make sense to implement a class, the search code could be simplified quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
machines.reject { |m| [*m['role']].grep('server').empty? }
```

Here a splat is used to produce an array from both `Array` instance and the `String` instance.

Comment: Thanks! Grep is my preferred course so I have the option if I ever need to use regex.

Comment: I prefer `machines.select { |m| [*m['role']].include?('server') }`, because it's one less step and, imo, reads better. If readers do not understand mudsie's last sentence, a simple example may help: `[*[1,2]] #=< [1,2]; [*'cat'] #=> ['cat']`.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code the roles can be string or array so safe to check using following

```
results = machines.select { |machine| Array(machine['role']).include?('server') }
```

Update: using Array, this method tries to create array by calling to_ary, then to_a on its argument.

Comment: Array() method tries to create array by calling to_ary, then to_a on its argument.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `'role'` can be a string or an array.

Using `#include?` will match part of a string if it's a string. Or fully match a string inside an array.

Try:

```
results = machines.select { |machine| machine['role'].include?('server') }
```

Or more robust

```
results = machines.select do |machine| 
  r = machine['role']
  if r.is_a? String
    r == 'server'
  else
    r.include?('server') 
  end
end
```

Comment: or you can use `Array(machine['role']).include?('server')`

Comment: @narensisodiya how about `machine['role'].to_a.include?('server')`?

Comment: @MarkThomas Strings don't have `.to_a`, do they?

Comment: @marcusshep They don't for me, and it's not in the documentation. What makes you think they do?

Comment: @marcusshep I already told you they don't for me, meaning I already tested that. That test results in `NoMethodError: undefined method \`to_a' for "foo":String.`

Comment: to_a method is not there for string. here is the doc [2.2](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) and  [2.4](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html)

Comment: `Class String; def to_a; [self]; end; end` - There. to_a for string

Comment: Sorry folks, `String` used to have a `to_a` method, it was removed at some point (maybe 1.9.something) and I forgot. You _can_ use `"foo".lines.to_a` but then that defeats the simplicity I was going for. So never mind.